# Problem with using the def to create a function in python

Tags: python, list, function

I'm trying to create a function `hasFinalLetter` which takes two inputs and creates a list of all the strings in strList that ends with a letter in letters.
Then create three actual lists with strings to prove that the function `hasFinalLetter` works and one of the actual lists has to give an empty output.

```
def hasFinalLetter(strList, letters):
    strList2 = []
    for strings in strList:
        length = len(strings)
        lastLetterString = strings[length - 1]
    for lastLetter in letters:
        if lastLetterString == lastLetter:
            strList2.append(strings)
    return strList2

#This will return empty list
people = ["Isaac", "Mitchel", "Priscilla", "Michael"]
lettersForPeople = "bLA"

print(hasFinalLetter(people, lettersForPeople))

# Case 2
things = ["Cars", "Phone", "box", "laptop"]
lettersForThings = "sexe"
print(hasFinalLetter(things, lettersForThings))

# Case 3
things2 = ["Car", "Phone", "box", "Laptop"]
lettersForThings2 = "rexp"

print(hasFinalLetter(things2, lettersForThings2))
```

However, there is something in my definition that makes my code output just:

```
[]
[]
['Laptop']
```

While the others are blank, even when `lettersForThings2` contains all the last words in `things2`.
I've been debugging for quite some time now and can't seem to find the source of the problem.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, still gives the same output

Comment: Please ! use `has_final_letter` and not `hasFinalLetter`, it's not pythonic at all

Comment: @DevLounge In my school we use `hasFinalLetter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the code below.

```
   def hasFinalLetter(strList, letters):

      strList2 = [ ]
      lastLetterString = [ ]

      for strings, letter in zip(strList, letters):

          length = len(strings)

          lastLetterStr = strings[length-1]

          lastLetterString.append(lastLetterStr)

          if lastLetterStr == letter:
              strList2.append(strings)
      return strList2 


   # This will return empty list         
   people = ["Isaac", "Mitchel", "Priscilla", "Michael"]
   lettersForPeople = "bLA"

   print(hasFinalLetter(people, lettersForPeople))

   # Case 2
   things = ["Cars", "Phone", "box", "laptop"]
   lettersForThings = "sexe"
   print(hasFinalLetter(things, lettersForThings))

   # Case 3
   things2 = ["Car", "Phone", "box", "Laptop"]
   lettersForThings2 = "rexp"

   print(hasFinalLetter(things2, lettersForThings2))
```

Output:

```
  [ ]
  ['Cars', 'Phone', 'box' ]
  ['Car', 'Phone', 'box' , 'Laptop']
```

Please redefine your function as shown above:

I tried sending a picture it didn't work since I'm new to Github, also tried commenting it didn't work too.....

You can send a mail personally to me via kelvinlikel@gmail.com
I got the exact output I believe you wish to have

Comment: Yeah, the code works. But you created a new list lastLetterString. Can you explain why?

Comment: Sorry my friend, it was there for testing purposes initially.  So I could print it and find out if the output is what I wanted. Please delete both lines containing lastLetterString thanks my friend

Answer (score 1):

There is bad indentation in function `hasFinalLetter`:

```py
def hasFinalLetter(strList, letters):
    strList2 = []
    for strings in strList:
        length = len(strings)
        lastLetterString = strings[length - 1]

        # bad indentation was here:
        for lastLetter in letters:
            if lastLetterString == lastLetter:
                strList2.append(strings)

    return strList2


# This will return empty list
people = ["Isaac", "Mitchel", "Priscilla", "Michael"]
lettersForPeople = "bLA"

print(hasFinalLetter(people, lettersForPeople))

# Case 2
things = ["Cars", "Phone", "box", "laptop"]
lettersForThings = "sexe"
print(hasFinalLetter(things, lettersForThings))

# Case 3
things2 = ["Car", "Phone", "box", "Laptop"]
lettersForThings2 = "rexp"

print(hasFinalLetter(things2, lettersForThings2))
```

Prints:

```
[]
['Cars', 'Phone', 'Phone', 'box']
['Car', 'Phone', 'box', 'Laptop']
```